# Удалить определенный файл по его номеру в scandir

Tags: php

Здравствуйте. Нужно удалить определенный файл по запросу ?delete=номер, этот номер определяется последовательностью в таблице. Как так сделать, чтобы при клике на ссылку типа мойсайт.ру/admin.php?delete=0 удалялся первый файл (сверху) из таблицы? Вот код:

```
<?php
$dir  = 'downloads';
$files = scan_dir($dir);
if($files == false) printf("Каталог пуст");
else printf("<table  class='bordered'>
<thead>
    <tr>       
        <th>Название файла</th>
        <th>Размер</th>
        <th>Удалить</th>
    </tr>
</thead>");

foreach($files AS $i => $filename) {
printf(
    '<tr><td><a download href="/downloads/%s" style="color:black">%s</a>   </td><td style="white-space:nowrap;">%s</td><td><a href="?delete=%d">del</a></td></tr>',
    urlencode( $filename),
    $filename,
    human_filesize(filesize( $dir . '/' . $filename)), $i
);
}


function human_filesize($bytes, $dec = 2) 
{
$size   = array(' Б', ' КБ', ' МБ', 'ГБ', 'ТБ', 'ПБ', 'ЕБ', 'ЗБ', 'ЙБ');
$factor = floor((strlen($bytes) - 1) / 3);

return sprintf("%.{$dec}f", $bytes / pow(1024, $factor)) . @$size[$factor];
}

function scan_dir($dir) {
$ignored = array('.', '..', '.svn', '.htaccess');

$files = array();    
foreach (scandir($dir) as $file) {
    if (in_array($file, $ignored)) continue;
    $files[$file] = filemtime($dir . '/' . $file);
}

arsort($files);
$files = array_keys($files);

return ($files) ? $files : false;
}
?>
```

Номер файла получается переменной $i в цикле scandir

Answer (score 1):

Так делать не надо. Порядок файлов, возвращаемых `scandir`, никто не гарантирует. Например, что будет, если на сервере появится файл "a", пока вы собираетесь удалить файл "b" в списке "b, c, d"? Передавайте имя файла.

Ну а само удаление тривиально:

```
if (isset($_GET['delete']))
    unlink("$dir/$_GET['delete']");
```

Только не забудьте проверять имя файла на наличие относительного пути типа "../../filename", а то вам весь сервер удалят. :)

Comment: Сделал как вы сказали. Не работает

`foreach($files AS $i => $filename) {
 if (isset($_GET['delete'])) unlink('./downloads/' + $_GET['delete']);
 printf(
        '<tr><td><a download href="/downloads/%s" style="color:black">%s</a></td><td style="white-space:nowrap;">%s</td><td><a href="?delete=%s">del</a></td></tr>',
        urlencode( $filename),
        $filename,
        human_filesize(filesize( $dir . '/' . $filename)), urlencode( $filename)
    );
}`

Comment: помоги, код выше

Comment: @Rasrow Запустите под отладчиком и скажите, в чём именно у вас проблема. Убедитесь, что имя файла корректно генерируется, что файл существует и т. п.